# How to retrieve the bounding box of a scalebar from a AnchoredSizeBar from Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am facing serious difficulties in retrieving the bounding box of a mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.anchored_artists "AnchoredSizeBar" object.

So far, all I found was how to insert (create) an AnchoredSizeBar into my figure. But I can't retrieve its position. A relative position in respect to its given axes would also be welcome.

Ultimately, I would like to make a AnchoredSizeBar as Behnam asks in[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786714/how-to-insert-scale-bar-in-a-map-in-matplotlib). But in order to do so, I would need to create a series of AnchoredSizeBars all contiguous one to another in the figure. In order to do so, I would need a function to retrieve their relative positions and apply those into the creation of the other AnchoredSizeBars, creating finally a full scalebar.

This subject is related to other links presented below:

1) [How to insert scale bar in a map in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786714/how-to-insert-scale-bar-in-a-map-in-matplotlib)

2) [Add fill_bar argument to AnchoredSizeBar](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/users/whats_new.html?highlight=anchoredsizebar)

Here is a snippet code of a desired API for AnchoredSizeBar object extent retrieval.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.anchored_artists import AnchoredSizeBar


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))

bar0 = AnchoredSizeBar(ax.transData, 0.3, 'unfilled', loc=3, frameon=False,
                       size_vertical=0.05, fill_bar=False)
ax.add_artist(bar0)


bar0_extent = bar0.get_extent()

fig.show()
```

I thank you for your time, sincerely yours,

Philipe Leal

Comment: That will become utterly complicated. I would opt for creating one single `AnchoredOffsetbox` with a `DrawingArea` or an `AuxTransformBox`; then add as many rectangles as you need to it to give it a (black and white kind of?) scale. You may look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43343934/4124317) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

To get the extent you can pass in `ax.figure.canvas.renderer` where `ax` is the axes to which the object has been added to:

```py
bar0_extent = bar0.get_extent(ax.figure.canvas.renderer)
```

But I second @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion for your particular use case. The doc-string for `AnchoredSizeBar` suggests that methods:

> Docstring:      An offset box placed according to the legend location
>   loc. AnchoredOffsetbox has a single child. When multiple children is
>   needed, use other OffsetBox class to enclose them.  By default, the
>   offset box is anchored against its parent axes. You may explicitly
>   specify the bbox_to_anchor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Prasanth, Thank you for your reply. It seems that ImportanceOfBeingErnest's alternative is OK. Nevertheless, I noticed a small problem to the given solution. The scalebar ends up always over the plotted axes. Therefore, if one has a Map of any given place (i.e.: a continent as Brazil), inevitably the scalebar will cover some of the Map. If possible, I would like to place the scalebar outside of the given axes. If possible, I would like to be able to set the scalebar position based on the figure.transFigure (figure transformation). Any ideas?

Comment: You could try passing `bbox_transform=transFigure` and `bbox_to_anchor=(x,y)` to `AnchoredOffsetbox`. With these options, I think, `loc` will be taken as the point of the box that will be placed at `(x,y)`.